# Chrome's "net-internals" reports Extensions not found on the GUI

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

If I browse to `chrome://net-internals/#modules`, a page that I just discovered a few minutes ago, a list of extensions is presented like so:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome net-internals "modules" page]

This list includes the following:

```
Entanglement Web App  3.4.9  Get more tangled than your friends to win the game of Entanglement.
Poppit!               3.1    Join prickly cactus Spike in a fun scramble to pop as many balloons as you can.
```

What the frak? I didn't install these! I've never even heard of them. chrome://extensions/` doesn't list them. Furthermore I can see no relevant toolbar icon or access to these extensions.

I'm the only user configured in Chrome.

Where did these extensions come from, perchance? How can I uninstall them?

*I'm running Chrome 57 on Windows 7 Pro SP1 (64-bit).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that those two applications [come pre-installed with any installation of Chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/dLllSmNlSII).

[image: Chrome New Tab page]

Comment: Aha! Plus, from this screen I _can_ remove them (I guess "apps" !== "extensions"??). Seems very naughty of Chrome, but very un-naughty of Oliver Salzburg: thank you!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition You're very welcome :)